# QT progress bar speed

Tags: c++, qt, progress-bar

Does QT provide any functions to control a progress bar's speed? For example, if I want it to increase by 1% every 1 second, is there any QT way to do it instead of using a loop and sleeping for 1 second between each value change?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [`QTimeLine`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qtimeline.html) for this. The detailed description in the documentation gives an example of exactly what you want.

Answer (score 3):

Use a QTimer.

Connect the signal `timeout()` to a slot that increases the value in the QProgressBar.

```
QTimer *timer = new QTimer(this);
connect(timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(update()));
timer->start(1000);
```

In this cas, `update()` will be call each second.

Comment: I'm using QTimer for something different, and it's very useful. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Qt 4.6 you can also use QPropertyAnimation